# Which techniques can be used to explore causality in repeated cross-sectional data?

Tags: time-series, causality, granger-causality, cross-section

I have repeated cross-sectional data for certain variables during 51 years (hundreds of variables, measured every year). The number of samples (individuals) for which these variables are measured in each year varies, with later years having typically more samples, but the number of measured variables remains constant. I would like to explore causality in this data between the measured variables during time. I know that Granger causality is usually used in time series, but since this is repeated cross-sectional data, it would not be the most canonical use for it. I can average values and apply Granger between averages, but I would like to find other ideas. I've searched for alternatives, but so far have not been able to find a good one. Does anyone have any advice on alternatives that could help me explore causality in time with this type of data?

Comment: How were you able to obtain **51** years of continuously measured information? That sounds almost impossible. As I'm in possession of several texts on panel data models, it was an easy check for discussions of causal relationships wrt this model structure. None of them discussed causality. Most commonly, causality is explored in the context of RCTs. In my opinion, you should step back and ask both *why* and *how* causal relationships could be discovered with data such as yours, esp. given that the individuals sampled change each year.

Comment: @MikeHunter I simplified it a bit to make it more general. The time points are different ages of the individuals, and the idea is to explore causality between variables as the individuals age. I figured the pratical effect would be the same as a repeated cross-sectional of 51 years. As to "how" causal relationships could be discovered with this kind of data, I don't know. That's why I'm looking for help from more experienced people. I'm begining in statistics, and I know it might not be possible, but this is what I'm trying to find out. From what I read, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You probably simplified too much. I think it's a mistake to employ panel data structures and thought to data like this. For me, more appropriate methodologies would be to explore various models of growth with the individuals treated as random effects, e.g., *Nonlinear Growth Curves in Developmental Research* provides one example. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3169758/

Comment: @MikeHunter I thought it was analogous. But ok, thanks for correcting me. You're probably right, though I'll have to think a bit more about it. And thanks for the article. I did experiment with nonlinear models, but it didn't work out very well. I wanted to find points of inflection when the variables begin to change, but I couldn't model it well, and I ended up settling for a linear mixed model, using individuals as random effects, for another analysis. Anyway, I will check the article you sent. But seems like there is no causality or interaction between variables there. But have to read all.